# googleapiclient Resource object's files() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-api-client

Following Google Drive API Python sample on this [section](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#multipart), there's a line

```
file = service.files().create(...)
```

The service is an instance of [Resource](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/v2.69.0/googleapiclient/discovery.py#L1342) returned from `googleapiclient.discovery.build()`.

What confused me was this files() method is not a member of Resource class and surprisingly it works (though as shown in the sample code we need to disable pylint error explicitly).

If we inspect this mysterious service.files() method:

```
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(service.files))
```

It points to [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/v2.69.0/googleapiclient/discovery.py#L1495) in the Resource class definition. This is where I get lost. Could anyone help explain how it works?

Comment: what is your question exactly? can we get an [example] please

Comment: it's not an issue. Everything works perfectly fine. Just want to understand the implementation detail, i.e. how is this files() implemented in the Resource - where is it added.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking into this, but if you're in the Resource class definition, you'll see that the `__init__` has a method called at the end, `_set_service_methods()`. It will dynamically create methods on the instance of Resource based on some other instance attributes (e.g. `self._resourceDesc`), which you can explore.

Basically, when a Resource is instantiated, methods like `.list` or `.get` are dynamically generated based on a predetermined schema, which you can find in the API docs most readily.

A Resource is essentially an API interface. The `discovery.build` method specifies which Google product's API you want to interact with. For example CM360 or DV360. The Resource object returned from the `discovery.build` call will have endpoints defined on it. If you chose the CM360 API, you'll get a Resource object with access to endpoints such as `advertisers` or `reports`. If you want to access, say, advertisers, you can add an additional call that matches the resource name (look at the API docs for this).

```
cm360_service = discovery.build(...)
advertisers_resource = cm360_service.advertisers()
```

Now, if you want a list of advertisers, you would add one more call:

```
http_request = advertisers_resource.list(**params)
```

When you make a call using a REST endpoint method (e.g. `.get` or `.delete`), instead of a Resource, it'll return a HttpRequest object (defined within `googleapiclient`). With this request object, you run `.execute(**more_params)` to make the actual request, and then you'll get data back.